# Mark a yaml file as deprecated

Tags: java, yaml, deprecated

Is there a way I can mark a **YAML/YML** file as deprecated just like a `class` of `method` in java.

The use-case is, there are a couple of YAML in my project directory which may not be being used currently. I simply can not delete it. is there any other way?

Comment: If the files are not being used, this is a sufficient precondition for being able to delete them. If you say that you can't delete them, then the question is why – for documentation, for backwards compatibility? Are you expecting to use them again in the future?

Comment: @flyx file is being used in a class I have marked as `deprecated`. I don't have access to delete anything. so I am marking as deprecated.

Comment: Ah, one of *those* projects. If the class is already marked as `deprecated`, what is your goal for also marking the YAML file? More specifically, what do you want to achieve that cannot be achieved by putting a comment in the YAML file that says it's deprecated?

Comment: someone will later clean it up. marking as `deprecated` will speedup the process.

Comment: Then I would suggest writing the file name(s) in a file for that person. No need to scatter the information into each file.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware of anything like that within YML (or Json, or XML), as these are only text formats, and there is no deprecation concept at all.

You can introduce, and use, some internal convention, and make sure that all will follow it in your context.

For example, add `.deprecated` file extension, and describe it in project documentation.

Or - to automate it - add some specific comment in yaml file, that will be looked up by your build mechanism, and display appropriate message during build process.

Hope it helps!